# To be vs have/has to be

Tags: grammaticality

the defintion of "task" word that google translator gives you is:-
a piece of work to be done or undertaken.
the question is:-
why are not it supposed to be : a piece of work (has) to be done or undertaken.

Comment: It could have been: “A piece of work *that* has to be done...” but “to be done” is more concise.  Dictionaries always strive for conciseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Has' is not necessary. 
'To be done' is used as an attribute in the sentence with the meaning of obligation.

Answer (score 1):

Consult in 'Oxford English Grammar' (p.124)
 'The pattern letters to write'
In this pattern the to-infinitive expresses necessity or possibility.
I've got some letters to write. (= letters that I have to write)
Take something to read on the train. (= something that you can read)
The doctor had a number of patients to see.
The to-infinitive clause here is shorter and neater than the finite clause with have
to or can.